# Is there any way to use where clause while parsing json data in android

Tags: android, json

Iam  daveloping **Android** App in that i need to parse **json** data.My json format is like this:

```
[
 {
"product": {
  "id": "120",
  "name":"prod1name"
  "description":"prod1description"
  },
   "product": {
  "id": "121",
  "name":"prod2name"
  "description":"prod2description"
  }   
 }
]
```

my parsing code:

```
JSONArray array=new JSONArray(text);
for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++)
{                   
    JSONObject json = array.getJSONObject(i);
    myJson = json.getJSONObject("product");
    productname.add(myJson.getString("name"));
    productdesc.add(myJson.getString("description"));
}
```

Now my doubt is:**is there any to get data as:get product name where id=120**
Any one plz help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can asks your API developer to send you json response for *id=120*. You can pass parameter in URL like `http://xyz.com/abc.php?id=12`

Comment: Could you parse the json data into a Map where the id is the key for another Map that contains product data.

Comment: Your json is not a valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this... I haven't tested it but it should get you started.

```
JSONArray array=new JSONArray(text);
Map<String, Map<String, String>> data = new Map<String, Map<String, String>>
for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++)
{                   
    JSONObject json = array.getJSONObject(i);
    myJson = json.getJSONObject("product");
    Map<String, String> product = new Map<String, String>
    product.put("name", myJson.getString("name"))
    product.put("description", myJson.getString("description"))
    data.put(myJson.getString("id"), product)
}
product_name = data.get("120").get("name")
```

Comment: thanq Larry McKenzie..but why are you putting name 2 times into product ( product.put("name", myJson.getString("name")))

Comment: Sorry, my bad I copied and pasted and forgot to change to description.